# A tag error deveria existir?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

A respeito do uso da tag [error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) gostaria de saber se é uma boa ela existir ou não. Penso que é uma boa ideia ela existir, mas vejo pouco uso dela mesmo existindo muitas perguntas com o tema desta tag.

O que acham amigos?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Me parece ser uma meta-tag genérica sem utilidade prática. Ela poderia ser aplicada a pelo menos metade das perguntas do SOpt, mas não daria significado relevante a nenhuma delas. E na minha opinião, ela não agrega nada as perguntas que foram "tagueadas" com isso. Acho que deveria ir para a lista negra.

Comment: Só discordo que seja uma meta-tag, de resto 100% de acordo!

Answer (score 6):

Removi a tag de todas as 16 perguntas. Agora é esperar o sistema apagá-la automaticamente.

Comment: Legal, muito obrigado :D

Comment: E ela está viva novamente :D Vamos testar um burninate?