# É um [erro] ter esta tag

Tags: debate, tags

Me deparei com a tag [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro). Neste momento esta tag está com 62 perguntas, a mais antiga delas parece ter sido criada em 17/01 deste ano.

Um detalhe interessante é que ela já tinha sido solicitada [de ser removida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5664/132) em 13/01. Ou seja, quatro dias antes da pergunta mais antiga que tem essa tag hoje.

A tag [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro) é extremamente ampla e genérica, não tendo utilidade alguma para categorizar nada. Ainda assim, se for eliminada de todas as perguntas na qual ela aparece, ela será recriada por algum usuário desavisado em pouco tempo.

Desta forma só vejo uma solução para isso: Lista negra. O famoso *burninate*. Eliminar de todas as perguntas e impedir que seja recriada. Essa tag deve ser exorcizada para sempre.

Como o colega UzmkArtanis apontou, essa tag [já tinha sido solicitada de ser excluída anteriormente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2516/132) (inclusive a resposta aceita por lá é minha). Mas essa tag havia ressurgido das cinzas de novo.

Comment: Eu creio que eu já tinha removido essa, talvez duas vezes, mas como sempre ela volta.

Comment: Não chega ser u merro ter, mas ela é tão mal usada que não sei se compensa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento talvez você tenha cometido um erro ao removê-la XD

Comment: Eu estou aos poucos removendo essa tag de todas as perguntas nas quais ela aparece. No caminho recomendei algumas para remoção e outras para fechamento. Logo logo a tag estará vazia.

Comment: Gostaria de sugerir a remoção da tag [tag:tratamento-erro] também. Essa tag tinha uma única pergunta e nem wiki tem. Não parece ter relevância suficiente para sustentar uma pergunta sozinha.

Comment: No caminho acabei removendo a tag [tag:aspas] das perguntas que a tinham também.

Comment: Tag esvaziada, será removida de hoje para amanhã se ninguém mais criar perguntas com ela.

Comment: @Renan Esvaziar a tag é a parte fácil. A questão é que tem que evitar a recriação dela. No SOen eles fazem isso no *burninate*, mas depende de ações de moderadores e *Community Managers*.

Comment: Precisa pedir pra fazer o *blacklist* da tag depois de remover.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [A tag error deveria existir?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2516/a-tag-error-deveria-existir)

Comment: @UzmkArtanis Quase isso. Quando criei esta pergunta estava procurando linkar essa outra. Observe que essa pergunta está como o [status-pronto] há muuuuuito tempo. Mesmo assim, essa tag ressuscitou pelo menos duas vezes. Assim sendo, isso serve como justificativa para ir à lista negra.

Comment: Realmente, fiz uma pergunta agora. De uma olhada https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6151/mudar-a-tag-error-erro-para-gerenciamento-erro?noredirect=1&lq=1