# Mudar a tag [error] e [erro] para [gerenciamento-erro]?

Tags: debate, tags

A tag [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro) está gerando muito problemas ultimamente, mas ela já é de casa e sempre volta, exemplo disso é que já temos uma pergunta relacionada a mais recente.

- [É um [erro] ter esta tag](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6115/%C3%89-um-erro-ter-esta-tag)
- [A tag error deveria existir?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2516/a-tag-error-deveria-existir)

E no wiki de tag da [error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) está escrito:

> NÃO USE esta tag se está com algum erro no seu código ou ambiente. Ela só deve ser usada em caso onde o erro seja o foco central da dúvida (gerenciamento de erros). Dê uma olhada nas perguntas nela antes de colocar na sua pergunta. É quase certo que estará usando equivocadamente. Um erro é derivado de uma ação ou processo que é impreciso e ou incorreto.

Então que tal se queimássemos as tags [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro) e [error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error), e trocassemos por [gerenciamento-erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gerenciamento-erro) (ou semelhante), as perguntas, assim como é recomendado no próprio wiki?

**P.S**: Podia deixar [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro), [error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error) como sinônimo da nova.

Comment: Esse é o problema, o pessoal ignora um pouco o que eu digo, mas se a comunidade se unir um pouco dá pra evitar, mas ainda sim o ideal seria que todos os sites da rede tivessem uma Blacklist própria para impedir o uso de certas tags. Por enquanto vamos ficando por aqui e aturando estes probleminhas.

Comment: Sou meio novato(5 meses) então to aprendendo @GuilhermeNascimento. Quanto ao fato de ser desunido todo lugar tem desunião. O importante é tentar diminuir esse fato. Seria muito legal, se houvesse um debate mais "caloroso e numeroso", para realmente termos um debate e não um diálogo

Comment: A idéia do blacklist eu achei que já existia. Vi no SOZão, e achei que já tinha aqui também. Talvez para moderação exclusivo, mas pelo que parece não tem. Já sobre os probleminhas é melhor tentar resolver, todos juntos, do que cada um ficar aturando. @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Sim, o problema é que essa "desunião" é que faz nem conseguirmos chegar a um dialogo pelo simples falta de interesse, mas não vou ficar aqui criticando, vou tentar uma abordagem diferente, estou formulando uma sugestão, vou postar no "Metão" e te mando o link ;) (o problema é que o pessoal lá também não se preocupa com estas coisas, vou torcer para que de certo, não que vire solução do dia para a noite, mas que pelo menos consigamos algum feedback)

Comment: Se for o caso, como não temos o "queimador", seria o caso de somente desvencilhiar as tags e melhorar o wiki @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Raramente alguém lê o Wiki.

Comment: Realmente, seria o caso de pensar em uma outra abordagem. Tipo "forçar o usuário" a marcar um checkbox, ou algo do gênero, talvez um tooltip. Dizendo que leu e entende o uso da tag @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: O problema é que os nem o Gabe e nem os moderadores editam o código fonte do site, não é só ter a ideia, ainda depende do setor de desenvolvimento deles avaliarem, determinarem prazos, determinar a melhor abordagem, criarem, testarem em alpha, testarem em beta (em apenas um dos sites da rede), depois de testado implementar nos outros sites, isso ae vai levar pelo menos uns 10 meses, levando em consideração que eles tem muitos outros trabalhos e coisas para arrumarem e "atuarem".

Comment: Não que eu esteja "engajado", quase morrendo, mas aos poucos estou tentando melhorar algumas tags. Isso seria o mesmo caso da tradução. Somente um tradutor não vai traduzir todo o SOpt, mas se todos colaborarem com um pequeno tempo da sua vida, não fica pesado para ninguém @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: >> https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6152/sugest%c3%a3o-blacklist-de-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment23696_6152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim e Não.

Sim pra queima da tag. Não para a criação de uma nova meta-tag que seria tão irrelevante quanto a original.

Eu acredito que tratamento de erro seria um assunto estéril. Teríamos no máximo algumas poucas perguntas que daria para contar na mão. Por vários motivos, mas principalmente porque:

- O tratamento de erros pode variar de acordo com a tecnologia utilizada. Por exemplo, os irmãos bastardos [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) e [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) possuem erros tipados, já seu primo [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) não tem. Só por causa disso a tag não seria independente por si só - dependeria sempre de outra tag especificando a linguagem.
- O tratamento de erros sempre existe dentro de outro escopo maior, que por si só já dará uma tag suficiente ao probema. Alertar o usuário sobre o erro ou silenciá-lo? [ux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ux). Passar erro a frente com ou sem rastreio de pilha? [engenharia-de-software](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/engenharia-de-software), talvez. Por que pessoas pedantes apoiam uma linguagem na qual você é obrigado a declarar explicitamente o tipo da exceção que um método talvez nunca lance? [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Etc., etc.
- [A tag não existe no SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error-management). Aquele povo é bem mais experiente que a gente, então se gestão de erros fosse algo relevante, teria uma tag por lá.

E por fim... Não estamos desinteressados em matar tags ruins e nem somos desunidos. Não dou uma semana para surgir mais um tópico sobre a queima de alguma tag e vai ter gente apoiando. Acontece que nós dispomos de ferramentas para lidar com esses problemas, então quem se sente incomodado pode ir lá e fazer a sua parte. Por exemplo, da última vez que a tag [erro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erro) morreu de novo, foi porque eu a removi de cinquenta e poucas perguntas. Ela foi apagada automaticamente no dia seguinte, sem a necessidade de se discutir mais sobre isso. Acho que se precisamos falar sobre tags, é para montar a lista do corredor da morte. Não para transformar um morto-vivo recorrente em outro tipo de monstro.

Comment: E parece que ela  [tag:error] voltou com mais 48 irmãs

Comment: @UzmkArtanis [tag:erro] e [tag:error] deveriam ser feitas sinônimas. A que eu ajudei a matar foi outra. [tag:error] tá no meu radar agora.

Comment: Bom, melhor começar, só falar não vai limpar o SO inteiro de tags lixo.

Comment: Assim não vale, suas sugestões são feitas na hora, eu não tenho esse privilégio. kkkkk

Comment: @UzmkArtanis quando você edita uma questão, mesmo que seja só para remover tags, ela recebe um bump. Só não mato tudo duma vez pra não fazer spam na página de entrada.

Comment: Aquele flood de leve

Comment: @UzmkArtanis continue participando, falta pouco pra você ganhar esse poder.

Comment: Seria mais interessante fazer isso em um horario de pouco movimento nao?

Comment: Pessoal, vejam: >> https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6152/sugest%c3%a3o-blacklist-de-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment23696_6152

Comment: Esses [dias](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=obsoleta) eu vi o @GuilhermeNascimento corrigindo algumas perguntas, foi por volta das 02h, nesse caso acho um horário válido para evitar o flood

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza concordo plenamente! Entre as 03:00h e 05:00h é o menos movimentado, creio eu, não tenho certeza.